# How to scroll to specific data on list using searchbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax, codeigniter

I have a searchbox and a div list populated by data from the database in my project. The idea is when I type something on searchbox it will be scrolled on the specific data on the list.  Thanks and have a nice day!

Here is the **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vEACM/1/)**

i have edited this question and add this script to my project but it still not scrolling.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('.search-field').on('keyup blur change', function() {
            var text_s = $(this).val();

            $("li#dirlist").removeClass("highlight");

            if (text_s.length > 0){
                $("li#dirlist").each(function(){
                    var li_value = $(this).text();
                    if (li_value.indexOf(text_s) >= 0){
                        $(this).addClass("highlight");
                        var x = getOffset( document.getElementById(this.id) ).left;
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }); 

    function getOffset( el ) {    
        var _x = 0;
        var _y = 0;
        while( el && !isNaN( el.offsetLeft ) && !isNaN( el.offsetTop ) ) {
            _x += el.offsetLeft - el.scrollLeft;
            _y += el.offsetTop - el.scrollTop;
            el = el.offsetParent;
        }
        window.scrollTo(_x,_y);
        return { top: _y, left: _x };
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you want

**JsFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/q52Fc/1/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span12">
            <div class="green-bar">
                <h4><center>Directory</center></h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </br>
    </br>
    <div class="span4">
        <div id="name-dir">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="control-group">
                    <div class="controls">
                        <div class="input-prepend"> <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-search"></i></span>

                            <input class="block search-field" id="inputIcon" type="text" placeholder="Search">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </br>
            <div class="contact-list">
                <div class="contact-gray-bar">A</div>
                <ul class="contact">
                    <!-- insert records here -->
                    <li>Apple</li>
                    <li>Amethyst</li>
                    <li>Aratilis</li>
                </ul>
                <div class="contact-gray-bar">B</div>
                <ul class="contact">
                    <!-- insert records here -->
                    <li>Banana</li>
                </ul>
                <div class="contact-gray-bar">C</div>
                <ul class="contact">
                    <!-- insert records here -->
                    <li>Cross</li>
                    <li>Cross</li>
                    <li>Cross</li>
                    <li>Cross</li>
                    <li>Cross</li>
                    <li>Cross</li>
                    <li>Cross</li>
                    <li>Cross</li>
                    <li>Cross</li>
                    <li>Cross</li>
                    <li>Cross</li>
                    <li>Cross</li>
                    <li>Cross</li>
                </ul>
                <div class="contact-gray-bar">K</div>
                <ul class="contact">
                    <!-- insert records here -->
                    <li>Kiwi</li>
                </ul>
                </br>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(function () {
    $('.search-field').on('keyup', function () {
        var first_result = false;

        var text_s = $(this).val().toLowerCase();

        //Reinit li elements and the contact-list position
        $("li").removeClass("highlight");
        $(".contact-list").scrollTop($(".contact-list").position().top);

        if (text_s.length > 0) {
            $("li").each(function () {
                var li_value = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
                if (li_value.indexOf(text_s) >= 0) {
                    $(this).addClass("highlight");
                    if (first_result == false) {
                        //Have to move to the 1rst element's position
                        first_result = true;
                        $(".contact-list").scrollTop($(this).position().top);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

**CSS:** no change done.

If you want to learn more about position, you can read this: http://api.jquery.com/position/

Answer (score 0):

Try Something Like

```
$(function() {
    $('.search-field').on('keyup blur change', function() {
        var text_s = $(this).val();

        $("li").removeClass("highlight");

        if (text_s.length > 0){
            $("li").each(function(){
                var li_value = $(this).text();
                //alert(this.id);
                if (li_value.indexOf(text_s) >= 0){
                    //alert(text_s);
                    $(this).addClass("highlight");
                    var x = getOffset( document.getElementById(this.id) ).left;                    

                }
            });
        }
    });
});

function getOffset( el ) {    
    var _x = 0;
    var _y = 0;
    while( el && !isNaN( el.offsetLeft ) && !isNaN( el.offsetTop ) ) {
        _x += el.offsetLeft - el.scrollLeft;
        _y += el.offsetTop - el.scrollTop;
        el = el.offsetParent;
    }
    window.scrollTo(_x,_y);
    return { top: _y, left: _x };
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ashuslove/vEACM/2/)

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer but it is still not scrolling on searched data. Do I need to use anchor for it to scroll?

Comment: I applied it on my project. It contains 300+ records but it is still not working. Maybe on the jquery version that i used?

Comment: I resize the fiddle. Yes you're right. Its working in here. But why it is not working when i apply it on my code? I have jquery-1.8.3.js on the versions that im using.

Comment: put your whole code here then you might doing something wrong with Jquery.. and one more thing do have scroll in your page if then then plz put and try it once..

Comment: I cant put the whole code here. it said that it is has too many characters. I just add your answer on my code and edit some.

Comment: I think I figured out why it is not working. The data that being search is hardcoded in jfiddle while in my project it is populated through database. How can I apply it for that?

Comment: Hi sorry. I'm not using jquery autocomplete. I used ajax to populate my list. i try to add this to the code ' $(document).ready(function () {
  $('.search-field').on('keyup blur change', function() {
   $('.contact-list').animate({
    scrollTop: $( $.attr(this, 'href') ).offset().top
   }, 500);
   event.preventDefault();
  });
 }); ' but it is still not scrolling when i insert something on search .it just stay on top.

Comment: I am taking 5000$ of development if you want help in everything then give me your project to develope :) ;)